# tmux how many windows in current session

Tags: tmux

In a bash script, I want to **get the count of windows in current tmux session**.

I found `tmux display-message -p '#I'` get count of pane in current window. But how can I get count of windows instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#I is not the number of panes in the window, it is the pane index - for number of panes you want '#{window_panes}'.

Similarly, for number of windows in a session you can do '#{session_windows}'.